# How to read JSON array and display image in Android

Tags: android, json, api

I am `developing android listing images app` where I got array from server side. But I have issue to read array or don't know how to get it.

Below array i got from server API call:

```
{"lists":["http:\/\/xyz.com\/projects\/photo\/birthday\/1.jpg","http:\/\/xyz.com\/projects\/photo\/birthday\/3.jpg","http:\/\/xyz.com\/projects\/photo\/birthday\/4.jpg"],"Status":"1"}
```

How to read it and `display images` in loop.

Thanks

Comment: Do you always want to show the same number of pictures or are you going to use a ListView with a dynamic number of images?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gson library for parsing json respose then you could simply write  a  separate class 
like this

```
public class ImageResponse{
    public String Status;
    public List<String> lists;
}
```

NOTE: when creating a class the object names of the class should match with the tag names from the server..

Then using gson

```
 ImageResponse detail = (new Gson()).fromJson(
                    response.toString(), ImageResponse.class);
```

where response is your response from the server

now u can access the list like

```
List<String> images =details.lists;
```

Now you have all the images in the list form, you can load the images using Picasso[lets say in a listview]

```
Picasso.with(context).load(images[0]).into(imageView);
```

For using this you should add GSON library to your dependency in your app gradle

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

There are many other method too, feel free to search and find out may be there will be more optimized code than this..